# Call to self static method not working

Tags: php, static, operators

I have a problem that's driving me crazy.
I have a static class where I perform some checks, this is the code:

```
class MyClass
{
  public static function globalChecks()
  {
    $result = true;

    $result = $result && self::checkAgency();
    $result = $result && self::checkAttribs();
    $result = $result && self::checkCategories();
    $result = $result && self::checkDistricts();
    $result = $result && self::checkTowns();
    $result = $result && self::checkTypes();
    $result = $result && self::checkUser();

    return $result;
  }
}
```

All of these methods are declared as public and static.
Well if I try to run it, PHP executes the first one, then it simply skips the other ones.
I tried to debug or brutally put a `die()` inside the method, but it doesn't work.

If I switch the variable with the method call (ie `self::method && $result`) everything works...
It seems operator precedence is involved in some way, but am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as soon as one of your method call will return false, the && operation won't execute the second part of the expression ! since False && anything is False.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
public static function globalChecks()
{
  return self::checkAgency()
   && self::checkAttribs() 
   && self::checkCategories()
   && self::checkDistricts()
   && self::checkTowns()
   && self::checkTypes()
   && self::checkUser();
}
```

Comment: +1/2, doesn't explain what's happening, but an appropriate cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the first false is set, short-circuiting will cause the method calls to be skipped--no reason to run them in an "and" if the first condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

If `self::checkAgency()` returns `false`, `$result` will be `false` and because of the left-to-right evaluation of logical operators such as `&&`, none of the other methods need to be evaluated as the evaluation is short-circuited.

Are you sure that this first method returns `true` in some of your test cases?